# What does the "at sign" @ mean in these symbol names?

Tags: linker-errors, elf

I'm debugging an undefined reference to the following symbol (elf amd64 stuff)

```
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6: undefined reference to `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
```

and so I grep the symbols in that file and find the same symbol but with another "at sign"

```
(pyws) STRM ~/.../etc/conda/activate.d  $ readelf -s  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 | grep uuid_generate
67: 0000000000002370   135 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 uuid_generate@@UUID_1.0
```

So my questions are:

1) what does the `@` sign mean in a symbol name?

2) what is the difference between `uuid_generate@@UUID_1.0` and `uuid_generate@UUID_1.0`

Comment: It looks like [symbol versioning](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SymbolVersioning).  I'm not well enough versed in that arcane art to offer you a *bona fide* answer, but chances are good that your problem arises from having mismatched libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A document in the page linked by @JohnBollinger provides the answer:

https://akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf

> The symbol defined using @@ is the default definition. There
>   must be at most one. It is the version of the symbol used
>   in all linker runs involving the DSO. No symbol defined
>   using @ are ever considered by the linker. These are the
>   compatibility symbols which are considered only by the
>   dynamic linker